# Sending Request Headers with Scrapy Spider to avoid 403 response Status

Tags: python, scrapy

I was making a request to a [website](https://www.11880.com/suche/makler/deutschland) but I am getting a `403` response. How can we send request headers with the scrapy spider so that we can get a `200` response?

Also, the website updates the cookies with a new request. Is it possible to rotate cookies with scrapy spiders when we make a new request?

```
# -*- coding': 'utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


    class MainSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'main'
        allowed_domains = ['11880.com']
        start_urls = ['https://www.11880.com/suche/makler/deutschland']
    
        def parse(self, response):
            print(response.body)
```

**Hoping for some answers.**

***Regards***

---

[image]

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html#the-network-tool

Answer (score 0):

**that means  dont have access right check your header perameter passed. it was incorrect**

Comment: Yes, so I want to know how can we pass the headers to the scrapy spider

Comment: yes you can pass header read here https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the `start_requests()` method and pass the `headers` argument.

```
import scrapy

class MainSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'main'
    allowed_domains = ['11880.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.11880.com/suche/makler/deutschland']
    headers = {
        'header1': 'value1',
        'header2': 'value2'
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, headers=self.headers)

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.body)
```

Comment: I am getting these errors for "yield scrapy.Request(url=url callback=self.parse, headers=self.headers)", unexpected token 'callback' and unexpected token 'headers'

Comment: Sorry! I missed a comma right after `url=url`, just updated the post.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't even notice it :D

Comment: It's still giving me a 403 response. What other ways can we do in order to get 200 responses? Is this because request header changes when we make a new request to the website and I am using old request headers that are expired?